# Detect duplicate in String using shift operator java

Tags: java, bit-shift, shift

I have troubles understanding this code that detects duplicates in string.

```
int checker = 0;
    for(char ch : seed.toCharArray()){
        int val = ch - 'a';
        System.out.println(val);
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0){ 
            // duplicate found
            break;
        }
        checker |= (1 << val);
    }
```

can someone explain me with an example how this works ?

Comment: It sets bits for each letter found (a is the first bit, b the second and so on) and then checks if the bit has already been set before. The bits are kept in an integer (which can store 32, so enough for the alphabet, but not if you have non-letters or upper-case).

Comment: You should post that as an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: @Thilo Ok, So if i had a BitSet in java where IF (bitset for 'current char') is ZERO we set it to 1 and move on ELSE if it is already 1 break out of the loop will be a similar approach ? and will use only 26 bits. (considering i am dealing with 'a' to 'z' only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, say for example `ch = 'c'`:

```
int val = 'c' - 'a' = 2; //The char value for 'c' is two greater that that for 'a'
```

then evaluate the `if` condition:

```
1 << 2
```

means "shift 1 two places to the left", which gives us binary 100, or decimal 4.

```
checker & 4
```

means "bit-wise and" between checker, ie check if that particular bit is already set.

if the bit was set, we are done, otherwise we perform

```
c |= 4
```

which means "c = c | 4", which is a bit-wise or that will set the bit corresponding to 'c' to 1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is using `checker` as a bit map: bit 0 for 'a', bit 1 for 'b', etc. It checks if the letter is already set `(checker & (1 << val)) > 0`, and if it isn't then it sets it `checker |= (1 << val)`